# How to add <li> to <ul> with data element from localstorage

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to create a list of input with unique values which are gotten from a array of objects. But for some reason it only iterates once and stops.

```
function loadLayer() {
//Get the object from local storage
var project = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('project'));

var projectLayers = project.layers

for (var x = 0; x < projectLayers.length; x++) {
    var x = createLayer(projectLayers[x].name)
    appendLayer(x)
  }
}
```

So project layer is basically an array like `[{id=1,name="bob},{id=2,name="kevin"}]`

```
function createLayer(name) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.className = "list-group-item"
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT")
  x.setAttribute("type", "text")
  x.setAttribute("value", name)
  li.appendChild(x)
  return li
}

function appendLayer(layer) {
  var layerList = document.getElementById("layerList")
  layerList.appendChild(layer)
}
```

and appendlayer just adds the li to the ul

However, after i run the program my  only has one

with a input with bob inside it. Where did the other no go. I tried printing to see if second loop was called but it didn't seem like it. I don't know why and been stuck for hours.

Comment: In your first for loop you overwrite the `x` variable. Try to use variable names that say something about the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you have been told, you need to be careful with the way you name variables.
Secondly I will also suggest using **let** instead of **var**. Because you could easily overwrite a variable declared with **var** outside its initial scope.

**And now to your code:**
I made some edit to your code especially the **loadLayer function** and it appends both names to the list:

```
<script>

    let projectList = [
        {
            id:1,
            name:"bob"
        },
        {
            id:2,
            name:"kevin"
        }
    ]

    function loadLayer() {
        window.localStorage.setItem('project', JSON.stringify(projectList));
        let p = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('project'));

        for (let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {

            let projectName = createLayer(p[i].name)
            appendLayer(projectName)

        }
    }


    function createLayer(name) {

        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.className = "list-group-item"

        let x = document.createElement("INPUT")
        x.setAttribute("type", "text")
        x.setAttribute("value", name)

        li.appendChild(x)
        return li
    }

    function appendLayer(layer) {
        let layerList = document.getElementById("layerList")
        layerList.appendChild(layer)
    }

    loadLayer()
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the fix. Will do some more research on when to use var and let. Was always confuse on those. Thanks alot

Comment: @Frostyfeet you're welcome. If I answered your question, you can please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are naming the variable of the iteration in the loop as `x` and the `var x = createLayer(projectLayers[x].name)` conflicts with it, change one of them.